# Regardless of input, it will always output using the A or a parameters

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

How do I get it to respond accordingly to inputs other than 'A' and 'a'? Note: No .toUpperCase() or like statements. It has to be able to handle 'A' and 'a'. Preferably keeping the switch statement

```
function Ticket() {
    var ticketType = prompt('What type of ticket do you want');
    var ticketQty = parseInt(prompt('How many tickets do you want'));

    document.write('Ticket type is: ' + ticketType + '<br />');
    document.write('Ticket quantity is: ' + ticketQty + '<br />');

    ticketPrice = 0;

    switch(ticketType) {
        case 'A':
            var ticketPrice = 100;
            break;
        case 'a':
            var ticketPrice = 100;
            break;
        default:
            ticketTypePrice();
    }

    function ticketTypePrice () {
         if (ticketType == 'B') {
            var ticketPrice = 75;
        } else if (ticketType == 'C') {
            var ticketPrice = 50;
        } else {
            document.write('Invalid Ticket Type' + '<br />');
        }
    }

    if (ticketQty < 1 || ticketQty > 100) {
        document.write('Invalid Quantity' + '<br />');
    }

    if (ticketPrice > 0 && ticketQty > 0 && ticketQty < 100) {
        totalticketPrice = (ticketPrice * ticketQty);
        document.write('Ticket Payment Required: ' + totalticketPrice);
    }
}

Ticket();
```

Comment: the problem is scope ... the var ticketPrice inside `ticketTypePrice` is not the same as the var ticketPrice outside that function

Comment: I have added ticketPrice and ticketType to the function ticketTypePrice, but it is still not working. Regardless of what I enter, it always uses 100 for ticketPrice

Comment: let me clarify ... the problem is scope ... the `var ticketPrice` inside `ticketTypePrice` is not accessible outside `ticketTypePrice` regardless of how you declare (or not) the `ticketPrice` outside of that function ... *scope*

Comment: I appreciate your help, however I am lost at what I need to do.

Comment: learn about scope perhaps - I'd help, but I don't help with code that uses prompt and document.write, as this is 1990's web page stuff